# "Run-time error "-2147417848 (80010108) Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: excel, vba, automation, userform

I have a userform in which I check if the name entered is in the database.

I distinguish between adding contacts and editing contacts in different forms, so if in the 'adding contacts' form a name is entered that is in the database, a vbYesNo MsgBox tells the user and gives the opportunity to either change the entered name (vbNo) or to edit the existing name (vbYes).

```
Private Sub cmbLastName_AfterUpdate()

    Dim FullName As String
    FullName = cmbFirstName & " " & cmbLastName

    Dim answer As Integer

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("List_Full_Name"), FullName) Then

        answer = MsgBox(FullName & " already included in contact list. Edit contact?", vbYesNo, "Error").

        If answer = vbYes Then
            Unload AddContact
            EditContact.Show
            Sheets("Engine").Range("C4").Value = "EDIT"
        Else
    
        End If

    Else

    End If

End Sub
```

The EditContact.Show appears to work, yet when I close the EditContact userform, the program crashes and shows

> Run-time error "-2147417848 (80010108) Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

When I press debug `AddContact.Show` is highlighted:

```
Sub ShowAddContact()

    Sheets("Engine").Range("C4").Value = "NEW"
    AddContact.Show

End Sub
```

This piece of code opens the AddContact userform and is invoked when the button 'add contact' is clicked in the worksheet. The Engine worksheet refers to a cell that is changed, dependent on whether an entry should be added to the database or an existing entry should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

To check what is the real cause of your problem you should go into VBA editor -> Tools -> Options -> General and then change error traping option to "Break in Class Module". Call the error again and this time Debug option show you exact line that cause the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, that does not appear to change anything. The AddContact.Show command is highlighted, yet I don't see how that might conflict with the vbYes option in the MsgBox as I unload AddContact there.

Comment: Maybe you shoudn`t unload AddContact just yet. Try to hide it instead (AddContact.hide) and unload it just after the "EditContact"  userform is being closed by user or the data was sucesfully updated.